# Login form using knockout binding doesn't work on Firefox, fine on Chrome

Tags: forms, firefox, knockout.js, autocomplete, passwords

This is utterly bizarre!  I have a simple username/password form:

```
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="LoginUserName" class="col-md-2 control-label">User name</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" id="LoginUserName" class="form-control" data-bind="value: userName, hasFocus: setFocus" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="LoginPassword" class="col-md-2 control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="password" id="LoginPassword" class="form-control" data-bind="value: password" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="LoginRememberMe" data-bind="checked: rememberMe" />
                        <label for="LoginRememberMe">Remember me?</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: login, disable: session.isBusy()">Log in</button>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </form>
```

First time through, it all works fine and the user is logged in. After logging out and re-entering the user name, the password field is auto-filled. No matter if this is left auto-filled or retyped, when the login method is called, the password field is empty!

If I change the password to an incorrect one it triggers firefox to pop up the "password has changed, do you want to update...?" box at the top of the page. Provided that I answer "yes" to this and then, after that login fails, enter the correct one then it all works and I can log in.

Why on earth is firefox blanking out the password in this circumstance?  Completely confused!

Comment: You didn't post any JavaScript so it's hard to give a definitive answer. However, a lot of auto-fill functionality doesn't trigger an event on the input field, so Knockout won't know the value has changed and won't update the observable. You also mentioned the field doesn't update if you then change the password manually. Do realize that you have to LEAVE the field before it will update, since by default the `valueUpdate` property is set to `blur`. You can add a binding on your input field `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` which will update the observable instantly as you type the password.

Comment: Yes, but in clicking the "login" button, logically I have to have left the password field.  Also this works perfectly in chrome - just not in firefox.

Comment: Yes, clicking the login-button technically triggers a blur on the password field, but in the past I've definetly experienced the last field I was in before clicking submit not being updated. I really recommend trying the `valueUpdate` property. Also, I think Knockout recently got some changes that enable detection of auto form filling. This could solve some of your issues, but I am not sure if you need to set a flag, and whether this feature is already in the 3.2.0 release.